# Pull tabs on insect screen

Tags: insect, screens

I am building an insect screen kit from ADFORS. I've built them before, I can get the mesh in, with the spine, no problem.

I also know how to install the tension springs.

What I do not know, is how to handle the pull-tabs (pictured below.)

The instructions do not explain how to install those. It only tells me to put them at top/bottom frame and opposite of the tension springs.

I don't know on which side of the frame they go. I don't know what goes first, mesh or pulltab?

Do I skip the spine at the pull-tab region, or does it need to go in both?

[image: pull tabs]

Comment: I think it is the mesh, the pull tabs and then the spline.  The you find out the tension springs are stronger than the tabs.

Comment: They should end up on the inside of the screen as installed, so they can be used from inside the house. Picture makes it unclear if they have a space for the spline to push into, or if they attempt to replaced the spline where they are placed.

Comment: Aside: One of the few good things I learned from a window replacement disaster was the easy way to remove the screens.  YMMV.  Rather than trying to use the finger slots on the bottom, just push up on the bottom edge of the top of the screen, directly below the springs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what it looks like on a replacement window/screen. Screen is mounted to the outside. Photo is from the outside. I hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: Awesome. The order `Frame -> Tab -> Mesh -> Spine` worked for me, indeed.